# Data can not be read from Firebase Database - Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

So basically, I am trying to get data from the database but I couldn't get it. When the read operation is commanded the process just goes on without any end, returning nothing so I have to intentionally time it out. I am able to write the data to the database. here is the algorithm showing what I am doing

```
importing file

//database is initialized in another file which is imported

reference = instance.reference();

Async getData(reference){
reference.once.then(DataSnapshot){print(DataSnapshot)}
}

void main(){
getData(reference)
}
```

Need help desperately. I shall be very thankful to the community. No apparent reason showing up.